# Get content from a XML file over http very slow

Tags: android, xml, httprequest, urlconnection

I try to get the content from a xml response over http from a source in my LAN.
When I open the url in my browser is the loading time 173ms but when I want to get it inside my APP the loading time is more than 15 seconds (tested with my phone, not emulator).

I tried this two ways:

```
    Log.d("start download",url);
    URL serverAddress = null;
    try {
        serverAddress = new URL(url);
        URLConnection urlConnection = serverAddress.openConnection();
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String source = "";
        String tmp;
        while ((tmp = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            source += tmp;
        }
        Log.d("end download",url);
        return source;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "FALSE";
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "FALSE";
    }
```

and

```
    Log.d("Starte download",url);
    try {
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        httpParameters.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 10000);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String source = "";
        String tmp;
        while ((tmp = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            source += tmp;
        }
        Log.d("Beende download",url);
        return source;
    } catch (IOException io) {
        Log.e("Downloader", "Couldn't downlaod " + url);
        io.printStackTrace();
        return "FALSE";
    }
```

tried also: urlConnection.setUseCaches(false) and urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(1000) with same result

**UPDATE:**

I add some Log.d to see what part needs the time:

From Log.d("start download",url); until Linereader: 180ms

10 ms pro 5 - 30 lines

The file have 3000 lines

Comment: Did you use the browser on your phone also? Or from a desktop?

Comment: The time is from desktop. When I open the url in the browser from my phone I see after 2 seconds the text and after 3 seconds the loading bar is ready.

Comment: And you're not doing this on the main thread right? (called inside an AsyncTask for example)

Comment: yes its running in a asynctask